# Setting Modality of JDialog blocks Observer

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, observer-pattern, jdialog

I have my observer pattern working fine for my JDialog, update() is called when my observer gets changed, as i would expect. I am also keeping a track of the observer count in my observable, (Which is 1 with the JDialog open).

I am now to trying to set the Modality of my JDialog in order to make my main window unusable while the dialog is open. However, if i use

```
dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

I can no longer see my JDialog in my observable object, and the update() does not get called. It appears as if its not setting the observer correctly.

Can anyone shed any light on this? What can i do to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often this problem is caused by not taking order of program flow into consideration.

Make sure that you set up your observer fully, including adding all listeners and starting any and all processes ***before*** setting the dialog visible. If you do any of this ***after*** showing the dialog, it will be blocked until the dialog returns.

For more specific help, consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Perfect thanks, can't believe i didn't think of that!

Comment: @LexWebb: all Swing programmers get bit by this sooner or later. Now when a similar question pops up here, you can pass this info on.